Associated types for generic struct?
I want to emulate the x86 al/ah/ax byte addressing behavior where al/ah addresses the low and hi bytes of the 16-bit ax register. I want it generic so that I can use it with not just u16/u8 values, but u32/u16 and u64/u32.
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
#[repr(C)] // Ensure field order
struct Halves<H> {
    lo: H,
    hi: H,
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
union Addressed<T: Copy, H: Copy> {
    whole: T,
    halves: Halves<H>,
}

You'd need to use the above as Addressed<u16, u8>, but the u8 is implied by the u16. It'd be better expressed as Addressed<u16>.
Clearly, H depends on T, like an associated type. Is there a mechanism in Rust to enforce a specific type H for a given type T?

"Is there a mechanism in Rust to enforce a specific type H for a given type T?" - yes, T needs to implement a trait with H as an associated type.

@kmdreko Yes, that's what I was missing. Thank you.

Yes, you can achieve this with custom trait and associated type (as was mentioned by @kmdreko), here's one way to do it:
trait Register: Copy {
    type Half: Copy;
    fn split(self) -> (Self::Half, Self::Half);
}
macro_rules! register {
    ($whole: ty, $half: ty) => {
        impl Register for $whole {
            type Half = $half;
            fn split(self) -> (Self::Half, Self::Half) {
                let u = self >> (Self::BITS / 2);
                let l = self & (Self::MAX >> (Self::BITS / 2));
                (u as Self::Half, l as Self::Half)
            }
        }
    };
}

register!(u16, u8);
register!(u32, u16);
register!(u64, u32);
register!(u128, u64);

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
union Addressed<R: Register> {
    whole: R,
    halves: (R::Half, R::Half),
}

impl<R: Register> Addressed<R> {
    fn whole(whole: R) -> Self {
        Self { whole }
    }

    fn halves(whole: R) -> Self {
        Self {
            halves: whole.split(),
        }
    }
}

#[allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    let short = Addressed::whole(42_u16);
    let int = Addressed::halves(42_u32);
    let long = Addressed::whole(42_u64);
    let longlong = Addressed::halves(42_u128);
}


